# Evaluating $\int_{0}^1\left(\int_0^{1}fdx\right)dy$, where $f(x,y)=\frac12$ for $x$ rational, and $f(x,y)=y$ for $x$ irrational

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

So, while solving problems on double integral I came across this weird problem:

> Let 
>   $$f(x,y) = 1/2,\ \forall x\in \mathbb Q$$
>   $$f(x,y) = \ y, \ \forall x\in \mathbb Q^c$$
>   then find  $$\int_{0}^1\left(\int_0^{1}fdx\right)dy$$

I have no idea how to approach this problem, First of all I am not sure whether this integral even exist or not .

Can anyone please explain to me how to think in this question ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [Lebesgue Integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration) to be able to do this, as the Riemann integral does not converge.

---

Let $1_{\mathbb{Q}^c}(x)$ be the indicator function of the irrationals.  From $$\int_0^1 c \cdot 1_{\mathbb{Q}^c}(x)\,dx = c, \qquad \text{and} \qquad \int_0^1 c \cdot 1_{\mathbb{Q}}(x)\,dx = 0 ,$$ it follows (since $y$ is constant in the inner integral) that your integral is $$\int_0^1 y\,dy= \frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: You mean $\mathbb Q^{\mathrm c}$; actually $\Bbb Q^{\Bbb C} = \{\Bbb C\to\Bbb Q\}$, the set of all functions from $\Bbb C$ to $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish  Is that what I originally wrote! Ha!

Comment: Ain’t no thing but a chicken wing